# How do I properly apply an unnamed function that was defined using the function arrow notation?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, notation

If I define a function using the $\mapsto$ notation, for example $x\mapsto{x^2}$, is it an abuse of notation to write $2\mapsto{4}$?

In my application, I am using the $\mapsto$ notation because I want to avoid having to name a large number of functions that I'm using but if I have to give the functions names when I show specific examples then it kind of defeats the point.

I want to show examples of how they transform their input (hence the potential abuse of notation).

Comment: That notation is correct. The only problem with not naming functions is that if you have several of them, it will be hard to know which one is meant without a label.

Comment: Exactly.  There's not much more work to writing $f: x \mapsto x^2$, so that then you can say $f: 2 \mapsto 4$.

Comment: why not write your functional application as: $(x \mapsto x^2)(2) = 4$ or adopt a complete set of notations from [lambda calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus).